# Getting ConnectionString of a BizTalk config file from a C# Application

Tags: c#, configuration, biztalk, configuration-files, biztalk-2010

I have a BizTalk config file that I want to use in my C# application. I'd like to get the connection string from the BizTalk config. Is there a way to do this? Simply put, I want to read a connection string from an external config file.

What I'm currently using in my C# app config is:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="foo" value="blah;"/>
    <add key="foo" value="blah;"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I get the keys by using this code:

```
connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configKey];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From an external .config file, as in not the current .exe's config file, no.

System.Configuration will always refer to the local .config.

To access another .exe's .config file, you have to treat it as just an Xml file with System.Xml.